# Rails 4 how to save via select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html-select

I have a view like this

```
<%= form_tag member_survey_path(@survey), :method => :post do %>
 <% @survey.each do |s| %>
  <td><%= s.title %></td>
  <td><%= select_tag 'survey[][status]', options_for_select([['AAA',"0"],['DDD',"1"],['BBB',"2"],['CCC',"3"]]) %> </td>
 <% end %>
<%= submit_tag 'submit', :class => "btn new_btn" %>
<% end %>
```

I have no idea how to do in the controller, and how to pass the survey.id

Comment: Why do you use `@survey.each do` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name attribute of your select tag to have the id of each survey:

```
<%= select_tag "survey[#{s.id}][status]" ....
```

This will build a params structure like this:

```
params = {:survey => {123 => {:status => 0}, 21 => {:status => 1}, 36 => {:status => 0}}}
```

where 123, 21 & 36 are the ids of survey objects.  Then, in your controller you can do this:

```
params[:survey].each do |survey_id, attributes|
  if survey = Survey.find_by_id(survey_id)
    survey.update_attributes(attributes)
  end 
end
```

If you want to make anything else editable in the survey within that form, it's easy to do:  eg if you wanted to edit the name as well, you could just add

```
<td><%= text_field_tag "survey[#{s.id}][name]", s.name %></td>
```

which would make a params structure like

```
    params = {:survey => {123 => {:status => 0, :name => "foo"}, 21 => {:status => 1, :name => "bar"}, 36 => {:status => 0, :name => "baz"}}}
```

and you still have all the attributes for the survey neatly contained in a single hash.

As an aside, it's not good practice to call variables things like "s" as it doesn't tell the reader (which could include you in the future) what it is.  Rails convention is to name active record objects after their class, so you would say

```
@surveys.each do |survey|
   ..etc
```

Comment: Thx ur answer, but maybe should change 'survey[#{s.id}][name]' in "survey[#{s.id}][name]", then it works ^^                           and ur explanation is really helpful to me!!!! thx very much

Comment: Oh, it doesn't work with single quotes? (took me a while to spot the difference between the two in your comment).  That's weird.  I don't know why that would be the case, they are both strings.

Comment: I don't know why, but in single quotes can't load #{s.id}, in double quotes can be loaded

Comment: oh of course, yes: that's a rule of Ruby: you can use #{} inside double quotes and backticks but not single quotes.  I'm sure there was a good reason for this at the time :)  I forgot about that - sorry!  I'll amend my answer in case anyone sees it in future and doesn't read the comments.

Comment: Okay,I got it!!!Thank you very much for your explanation.You are really a nice guy.^^